# Integrating SVN with Trac - dll load failed

Tags: svn, trac

I have a **Wandisco SVN server** installed using :WANdiscoSubversion_1.7.8-2.exe from Wandisco site on a Windows 2008 R2 server.

I am using **Python 2.7.5 (32 bit) and Trac 1.0.1** on the above mentioned server.

I need to get **SVN integrated with Trac for bug tracking** purposes within my project.

While working on this, I installed the **svn python bindings** from :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.8/apache22/svn-win32-1.7.8_py27.zip

I unzipped this folder and copied the libsvn and svn folders to python installation dir/Lib/site-packages.

Now when I try to sync the trac repository with my svn repository I get the below error:

```
`C:\Python27\Scripts>trac-admin C:\apps\secbusnew repository resync "rtcdummy"
TracError: Unsupported version control system "svn": DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. `
```

I googled around, found and tried a lot of solutions but unfortunately nothing has worked.

As suggested on trac website (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion) i tried running "from svn import core" in the python command line and i get the below error:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 
>>> from svn import core
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svn\core.py", line 26, in <module>
from libsvn.core import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 25, in <module>
_core = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_core', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`
```

Can anyone please help me fix the above mentioned issue ?

Regards

Sowmya Dass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DLL is not found (likely INTL3_SVN.dll) which can be seen with Dependency Walker. That DLL is not part of Wandisco svn server binaries. Maybe also some other stuff with incompatibilities between Python and its SVN bindings can happen.

A solution is to install Bitnami Trac Stack 1.0.1 and copy its Python bindings to your Python installation directory, because that is a consistently concerted system.